# I see the following error when running the "saveastextfile" function for RDD using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o68.saveAsTextFile.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1089)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1062)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1027)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$3(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1009)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1008)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$2(PairRDDFunctions.scala:965)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:963)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$2(RDD.scala:1623)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1623)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1(RDD.scala:1609)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1609)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:564)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile$(JavaRDDLike.scala:563)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```